# Is there a secure way to view an attachment in a record for outsiders?

Tags: attachment, document

If a user adds an attachment to a record, is there a secure way to share that attachment to people outside of Salesforce who doesn't have a Sf license or is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly see attachment outside the Salesforce but Documents can be seen.

For attachment there is work around where a site page needs to be created which accesses the  attachment.

Comment: Yes but how secure is site.com? We only want specific people to see the document and some of those are not salesforce users. Any workarounds?

Comment: Force.com site is fully secured. You can restrict the acceas based on the ip of the device. So add the ip of the devices from which you want to access the file. If the url is accessed from outside the ip range  it will show an error.